# SharePoint "Did you mean" returning suggestion that is spelled the same as the search term

Tags: 2013, search-results

We're seeing a strange issue where the SharePoint "Did you mean" feature is returning a suggestion spelled exactly the same as the search term.
[image: Example of did you mean spelled the same as search term]

Our Search spelling dictionary is set to Dynamic so we're not sure why this would be happening.

We did find an article mentioning similar behavior when users clicked on a refiner from the search results but that is not the case with us.
[DYM not working with refiner](http://www.sharepointsearch.ch/mean-not-work-refiner/)

I'm wondering if anyone has seen this behavior and any suggestions about a fix besides modifying the display template to stop showing the DYM suggestion if it matches the search term.

More Info:
I was able to figure out an instance that causes the duplicate results although I'm not sure why. This query in our search results web part causes the issue:

{SearchBoxQuery}  ((ContentClass=STS_Web OR ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39*) -ContentClass=STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary) OR (BCSEntityName=IHITV) OR ( PartialPath:/communities/blogs/)

This one doesn't:

{SearchBoxQuery}  ((ContentClass=STS_Web OR ContentTypeId:0x010100C568DB52D9D0A14D9B2FDCC96666E9F2007948130EC3DB064584E219954237AF39*) -ContentClass=STS_ListItem_DocumentLibrary) OR (BCSEntityName=IHITV)

Answer (score 6):

I had this issue in a project where we were using * on the end of a query.

In a completely ootb search site, add * to the end of a word or words, it will come back with the suggestion being the same as the query.

It only does this in SharePoint 2013 on premises, and not in Office 365. I contacted Microsoft regarding this to find out if there was a patch to fix it, but had no luck.

It doesn't look like you are using wildcards for the search term, but thought this information might be useful for others.

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior in SharePoint 2016 on premises

Comment: No changes in SharePoint 2019